# C _Generic default return argument

Tags: c, generics, gcc

I need to use _Generic in C, to be able to return specialized values according to the variable type.

```
const char *encode_char_ptr(char *x)
{
    return (x ? x : "NULL");
}
....
#define encode(x) _Generic((x), \
    char *: encode_char_ptr, \
    const char *: encode_const_char_ptr, \
    bool: encode_bool, \
    default: return_param)(x)
```

so that for various types there's a specialized handling that returns some string, but for the rest (default), the argument itself will be returned. What could be a possible implementation for "return_param"? or do i have to implement a specialized function for each possible type?

Comment: What should the return value be in the default case? 42?

Comment: as written: "for the rest (default), the argument itself will be returned": x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the functions within the generic selection branches, and then the default branch can simply evaluate to the value of the argument. The only complication is that **all** branches must be semantically valid. So we can do a trick here for **scalar types**: make another generic selection. If it is of proper type then return the argument as is, otherwise return 0 cast to that type, producing 0 for arithmetic types, or null pointer for pointer types. The branch would not be evaluated so it is safe. Therefore we get

```
#define coerce_scalar(type, arg) _Generic((arg), type: (arg), default: (type)0)

#define encode(x) _Generic((x), \
    char *: encode_char_ptr(coerce_scalar(char *, (x))), \
    const char *: encode_const_char_ptr(coerce_scalar(const char *, (x))), \
    bool: encode_bool(coerce_scalar(bool, (x))), \
    default: (x))
```

This is possible to expand to structure, union types too by using a compound literal for the other branch initialized with `{0}` - though mostly I guess it would be pointers to structs, i.e. scalars again.

But the real solution would be to not call `encode` at all for other types.

Comment: Thanks! very elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Is the internal _Generic evaluated separately from the external one? or are they evaluated together? (evaluating coerce_scalar when reaching it in char * for instance).

Comment: Each branch of `_Generic` selection is always considered for *semantics* which means that every branch must be semantically valid for the given arguments. Only those branches that will be chosen will be evaluated.

Comment: *"If a generic selection has a generic association with a type name that is compatible with the type of the controlling expression, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association. Otherwise, the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in the default generic association. None of the expressions from any other generic association of the generic selection is evaluated."*